# Change in angular diameter of Cepheid variables

Tags: luminosity, angular-diameter, cepheids

I'm a highschool student and in the process of writing a research paper of deriving period-lumniosity relation of Cepheid variable independently of the pre-existing PL relation. Thus, I need to derive distance to each Cepheid variable independently by using, for example, trigonometric parallax and Baade-Wesselink method.

In the process of using Baade-Wesselink method, I need to calculate the change in angular diameter, which is represented by ∆θ. The question is, how can I derive that value given fluxes from different bands (V,B, etc.. I'm using the SIMBAD database currently).

Which definite equation do I need to use to derive it?

Comment: What exactly is the data you have? Do you only have only have the total flux of the star in various bands and not an image? Have you seen [this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1210.7150v1.pdf)?

Comment: @zephyr Thank you for the reference. The paper is the one I was looking for. The data I have is lists of V-R values and uncertainties over the period.